# How to get images from Instagram cropped in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I was using curl to get images from my Instagram and until 2 months ago the standard_resolution tag was cropped by default, however, now they are appearing in their original sizes. How can i get the images cropped again? Here is my code

```
<?php
    function gallery() {

        $user_id = ;
        $client_id = "";
        $token = "";
        $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/".$user_id."/media/recent/?access_token=".$token;

        function fetchData($link) {
            $ch = curl_init(); //initalise curl session
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link); //url to process (can be fed directly into init parameter)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //does not  check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate (optional)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); //do a regular HTTP POST if set to 1
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); //info type
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //set to true stops it returning json as string 
            $output = curl_exec($ch); //executes curl session 
            curl_close($ch); //close curl session
            return $output;
        }

        $result = json_decode(fetchData($url)); //Decodes a JSON string
        $posts = $result->data;

        foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
            <li class="gallery__item">
                <a target="_blank" href="<?=$post->images->standard_resolution->url; ?>">
                    <img class="gallery__img" src="<?=$post->images->standard_resolution->url; ?>">
                </a>
            </li>
    <?php }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the instagram api, but maybe something like [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.imagick.php) can help you. Although it's probably far from what you need in case you don't find another solution you still have this! :D

Comment: Thank you I will have a look to see if i can make it work with that